# Can a wight killed with dragonglass be reanimated?

Tags: game-of-thrones, weapon

Can a wight killed with dragonglass be reanimated by the Night King?

Comment: I have upvoted both answers but downvoted the question. They provide interesting insights and good demonstrations to effort in what seems like a logically simple question that really doesn't need to be asked.

Comment: If the answer should be based on the tv-show, it should be "Whichever we (D&D) think is coolest". If it should be based on GRRM's source material, wights probably cannot be killed by dragonglass. At least not in the magical sense.

Answer (score 8):

There is no evidence that I am aware of that shows they can be reanimated once killed by dragonglass (or fire for that matter).

From the [wiki](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Wights):

> Just like the White Walkers, wights can also be killed permanently by weapons made of dragonglass or Valyrian Steel.

We do know that when dismembered by traditional weapons the body parts can still move on their own (a good example of this is when Jon brings the wight to Kings Landing and Qyburn inspects the arm).

The books are no help here either as we have not seen a wight killed by dragonglass (the one Sam stabs is not effective because the dagger shatters on the armor). While Melisandre explains fire and steel will work.

> Necromancy animates these wights, yet they are still only dead flesh. Steel and fire will serve for them. The ones you call the Others are something more.
>
> <sub>A Storm of Swords, Chapter 78, Samwell V.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

We don't know but probably not. Wights can be killed by fire, dragonglass and Valyrian Steel in the show (slight difference to the books where normal weapons should work fine). Using the information and the fact that the Free Folk burn their dead to stop them reanimating we can probably say that they will not be able to be turned again else burning them in the first place would be pointless.

> **Jon Snow:** We should burn them.
>
> **Othell Yarwyck:** Snow's not wrong, My Lord. Fire will do for them. The Wildling way.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 1 Episode 7, "The Pointy End"</sub>

> **Samwell Tarly:** They were touched by White Walkers. That's why they came back. That's why their eyes turned blue. Only fire will stop them.
>
> **Jon Snow:** How do you know that?
>
> **Samwell Tarly:** I read about it in a book. A very old book in Maester Aemon's library.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 1 Episode 7, "The Pointy End"</sub>